# Grant access to master db

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL server instance with databases:

1. master - as always
2. MyApplication - my custom DB

In "MyApplication" db I already created a user called "MyUser".
The user "MyUser" cannot see the "master" db. The only permission that it has is to the "MyApplication" db.

I want to give "MyUser" permissions to access the "master" db. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure they can't see the Master database right now? It could be that you've created a database scoped user.

You can create the login on the master, then create the user in both master and the target application database.

In the Master database run the following:

```
CREATE LOGIN youruser WITH PASSWORD='SomePassword'
CREATE USER youruser FOR LOGIN youruser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

This will create the login on the logical server and a user for that login in the master database. You can then open a connection to the target database and run the following command to create the user there tied to the same login.

```
CREATE USER youruser FOR LOGIN youruser
```

In the target database you'll be able to add them to whatever role you'd like. In the master they will not have the same permissions as the "server-level principal login".

By doing these steps the user is the same login for both master and your target database. Note that by doing this with the same login if the database is moved to a different server (say because you restored it there for some reason) the login won't exist on the new server and you'll get permission errors. There are ways to add the login and clean up the SID descrepancy.

Comment: I had to create the user on the master for an existing user.|
CREATE USER youruser FOR LOGIN youruser